# Dynamically adding a custom layout one below other

Tags: android

[image]I have to add a custom layout in a relative layout on a button click.
Again on another click add that same layout with another values above the previous inflated layout.
and it will continue like this.
I don't want to use list view.

I can add dynamically my custom layout but how to place it above the previous added.

on click of ADD button a new row will be added to my relative layout in xml, like ROW 1, ROW 2, and this will continue with ROW 3, ROW 4 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the addRule method of RelativeLayout.LayoutParams class. For example:

```
RelativeLayout.Layoutparams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)button.getLayoutParams();
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_RIGHT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.LEFT_OF, R.id.id_to_be_left_of);

button.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Doing this, you can set programmatically all params you would set in your layout xml file.

Comment: but i want to place the custom layout above the previous added custom layout and this will go on.

Answer (score 1):

on button click event add this code:

```
            LinearLayout linearLayout=(LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.layout);
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);


            LinearLayout layout=new LinearLayout(getApplicationContext());
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params1 = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
            layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
            layout.setLayoutParams(params);
            Button button1=new Button(getApplicationContext());
            button1.setLayoutParams(params1);
            button1.setText("button");


            layout.addView(button1);
            linearLayout.addView(layout);
```

Define the layout having id @+id/layout and orientation Vertical in XML file.You will find the button layout being added on every click event.

Comment: Please look the image i have added.